# Windows 7 "Set Network Location": global or per interface?

Tags: windows-7, networking, 3g, windows-networking, gprs

Whenever I plug in my wireless modem on Windows 7, I get the following dialog:

[image: Set Network Location]

It's not entirely clear to me whether the option "*Treat all future networks that I connect to as public, and don't ask me again.*" will affect all future network connections, only the connections made with this network interface, or only connections to this network.
Ideally, I'd like all connections made with this device (a Nokia N900 phone with 3.5G) to be "public", but leave the Wi-Fi and wired adapters alone, since they will usually connect to my home network.

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Also, how would I undo the setting I choose here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get this message every time you plug it in, then Windows is constantly recognizing this as a new device, and I see at the top that at the end of the modem name it says **"29"**, probably meaning that you have connected this for the 29th time.

The choice that you make here only affects this network connection. This dialog box is on a per-connection basis, unless you check that box at the bottom that says:

**"Treat all future networks that I connect to as public, and don't ask me again."**

To undo this setting:

1. Log on to the network.
2. Open **Network and Sharing Center** by clicking the **Start** button , clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **Network and Internet**, and then clicking **Network and Sharing Center**.
3. Click **Customize**, and then click either **Public** (for "Public place" networks) or **Private** (for "Home" or "Work" networks).   If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
4. Click Next, and then click Close.

**UPDATE**: Seeing as you have already connected your home devices, Windows should remember that, otherwise, follow the steps for manually setting the location for each device whether it be wired or wireless and still retain the settings to make all future connections to **New** networks public.

Comment: Oops, I meant to ask whether the "_Treat all future networks [...]_" option was global or per interface. Edited question to reflect that.

Comment: The *"Treat all future networks [...]"* is global. Not on a per-connection basis.

Answer (score 1):

This setting is per connection so every time you connect to a new network it will ask you what kind of connection it is: public, work, or home (domain is only available for computers joined to a domain).

- Choose Home network for home networks or when you know and trust the people and devices on the network. Computers on a home network can belong to a homegroup. Network discovery is turned on for home networks, which allows you to see other computers and devices on the network and allows other network users to see your computer.
- Choose Work network for small office or other workplace networks. Network discovery, which allows you to see other computers and devices on a network and allows other network users to see your computer, is on by default, but you can't create or join a homegroup.
- Choose Public network for networks in public places (such as coffee shops or airports). This location is designed to keep your computer from being visible to other computers around you and to help protect your computer from any malicious software from the Internet. HomeGroup is not available on public networks, and network discovery is turned off. You should also choose this option if you're connected directly to the Internet without using a router, or if you have a mobile broadband connection.
- The Domain network location is used for domain networks such as those at enterprise workplaces. This type of network location is controlled by your network administrator and can't be selected or changed.

From [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Choosing-a-network-location)

In order to change a connections "location" go into the network and sharing center in Control Panel and click the link below the connection that has the current location set (in my case it is "home"):

[image]

It should then bring up the original screen you choose the locations from:

[image]

For more information see this [article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Choosing-a-network-location).